# Error when running composer require on a laravel 5 install

Tags: laravel, composer-php, package

I'm trying to run the command `composer require xavrsl/cas:dev-master` and I get the output below

```
    ./composer.json has been updated
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

     Problem 1
    - Installation request for xavrsl/cas dev-master -> satisfiable by xavrsl/cas[dev-master].
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.0.7
- xavrsl/cas dev-master requires illuminate/support 4.x -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
- don't install illuminate/support v4.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.0.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.0.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.0.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.0.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.0.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.0.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.14|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.18|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.29|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.8|don't install laravel/framework         v5.0.7
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.9|don't install laravel/framework         v5.0.7
- Installation request for laravel/framework == 5.0.7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.7].

    Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I'm trying to install this package into a laravel 5 app. I'm not sure if it's just an issue with Laravel or if it's actually an issue with my composer install.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks to me that the package you are trying to install is not compatible with Laravel 5. This is also obvious from the text on the [project's github page](https://github.com/XavRsl/Cas): **CAS server SSO authentication in laravel 4.x**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That package's `composer.json` is looking for `illuminate/support` 4.0, so composer is throwing an error because the versions cannot be satisfied. The package hasn't been updated to work with laravel 5 yet.

See: https://github.com/XavRsl/Cas/blob/e05fdbc11748ed1fe1a572aa223dc9f246045a28/composer.json
https://github.com/XavRsl/Cas/issues/14

Edit: Seems there is a develop branch that is updated to laravel 5 (As always thats underdevelopment so be weary of using it)

`composer require xavrsl/cas:dev-develop`

Comment: Thanks Wader, hmm I thought that might be the issue. Though I was looking on packagist I think and when doing a search it said it was compatible with Laravel 4 and 5. Anyway, greatly appreciate the answer.

Comment: @geocalleo see my edit. Looks like theres a development branch